# How to controll the webview in the scrollview with the scrollview's controller?

Tags: cocoa

Usually, In the scrollview is a tableview or textview, and then We can control the page with the scroller on the right or at the bottom. Now I want to put the webview instead of the tableview or textview , and I don't wnat to controll the webpage with the safari's controller and with the scrollview's controller, but I don't know how to do? and if I can disable the safari's controller or not , How to do ? Or someone can give me a sample ? Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your web view in your nib, then choose “Scroll View” from the “Embed Objects In” submenu in the “Layout” menu.

If, for some reason, you're constructing the view hierarchy programmatically, then create an NSScrollView and set the web view as the scroll view's document view.

Comment: Yes I can embed a webview in a scrollview ,but Now I want to use the scroller on the left of the scrollview to controll the content of the webview , not controll it with the controller of the webview's safari.

Comment: The web view doesn't use Safari; that's a separate app. Also, as of IB 3, the web view doesn't come with its own scroll view; you embed it in one yourself. And why on earth do you want the scroller on the left side? Are you trying to confuse your users?